# Customize Request Timeout while publish message to SQS using java sdk - Reducing SQS Message Processing Time: Minimizing Retries after 10 Seconds

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, httpclient, amazon-sqs, spring-jms

We are using SQS in our Java Spring Boot Project. While publishing messages to SQS, most of the messages are processed in <=300ms. However, some requests took more than 50 seconds. Upon initial investigation, we found that the SDK retries failed requests, taking 50 seconds to mark them as failures before initiating retries. In most cases, the message is reprocessed within <=300ms after the initial retry (resulting in a total time of around 50,300ms).

We aim to minimize the request time to 10 seconds, ensuring that retries happen after a maximum of 10 seconds in case of failure. We've already attempted some configurations.

If you need further help or specific details, feel free to ask!

```
    @Bean
    public ClientConfiguration getClientConfig() {
        ClientConfiguration clientConfig = new ClientConfiguration();
        clientConfig = clientConfig.withSocketTimeout(7000);
        clientConfig = clientConfig.withRequestTimeout(9000);
        clientConfig = clientConfig.withConnectionTimeout(11000);
        clientConfig = clientConfig.withClientExecutionTimeout(13000);
        return clientConfig;
    }

    @Bean
    public AmazonSQS amazonSqs() {
        String region = !StringUtils.isEmpty(sqsRegion) ? sqsRegion : AWSConfigConstants.AWS_SQS_REGION;
        return AmazonSQSClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(region)
                .withClientConfiguration(getClientConfig())
                .withCredentials(InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.createAsyncRefreshingProvider(true)).build();
    }

    

   @Autowired
   private AmazonSQS amazonSQS;
   private String queueName=DEFAULT_QUEUE_NAME;

   public void send(String message){
      long startMillis1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
      SendMessageResult result = amazonSQS.sendMessage(queueName,message);
      long startMillis2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
      long totalTimeTaken=(startMillis2-startMillis1);
   }
```

SQS java sdk dependencies which I used

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sqs</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.262</version>
        </dependency>
```

> Java version = 17

Ref Link which I follow

- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/tuning-the-aws-sdk-for-java-to-improve-resiliency/

asked same on github also

- https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/3054